# Print images via Bluetooth printer Android

Tags: android, image, printing, bluetooth

Hello i am new in developing Android applications, 
I need to create an application (Tablet - Samsung 10.1 Android ver 3.1) that will print images via Bluetooth printer (Canon CP800 - SELPHY), i have tried IPrint and no success with that, is this possible to get an API to print images via my application?

I would prefer an open source solution but if not i will be able to buy it.

Error that i receive when i am searching a printer:
Service discovery failed. Unable to connect to the printer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is working, i have tested it.
Thanks for ShadowCloud!

[Sending a File using Bluetooth OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577481/sending-a-file-using-bluetooth-obex-object-push-profile-opp)

Comment: did you mean,will the printer work if we send an image file to printer?

Comment: @IamStalker please see my issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440132/bluetoothshare-print-images-via-canon-cp-900-800

Comment: @IamStalker can i have demo code, that will print images via Bluetooth printer (Canon CP900 , CP800 - SELPHY)