# How to transfer data through bluetooth in android without using UIID and sockets?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Hello everyone I want to send some data via bluetooth from one device to another device but tthe problem is that second device dont have this application installed so i dont know the uiid so i can not use sockets so how to send via using  second device os bluetooth service.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to send?A file or something else?

Comment: i want to send text and files..

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178809/send-file-using-android-bluetooth

Comment: Mr Goutam sorry to say but mu code not recognize BluetoothShare?

Comment: I did not get what do you mean

Comment: Sir I mean the link you have provide is having Bluetoothshare in their code  when i use this code Bluetoothshare is not get recognized in my code so tell me what is Bluetoothshare here?

Comment: Please go through second answer

Comment: I have paired my device with my customized code i want code which will fit in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method

```
public void sendFileToDevice(BluetoothDevice device,String path){
        File file = new File(path);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: can u please tell that how i will perform using socket in remote device using their base bluetooth uiid

Comment: For that there is a good documentation in  android developers website.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: But they have not tell how i get the base bluetooth uiid of remote device?

Comment: UUID is not something like you get from the device,You just use generate uuid from online generators like this https://www.uuidgenerator.net/ and use in both the devices

Comment: sir but the problem is that if i have to use the socket approach then i sholud have the uiid of remote device bluetooth as i have not installed my app on both devices so it is not possible to use mu own uiid so i have to use the system bluetooth uiid

Comment: While using socket approach the one device works as server and other works as client. So the only way i know is installing apllication on both the sides.and I hope the what you system uuid may be some random uuid

Comment: But the thing is that if i use your suggested solution then i think it only work  for small data transfer for large files it not work?

Comment: How mush big file you want to send

Comment: around 10 mb and even your code not working for small files even for text.

Comment: For me it worked for even 60MB file,What is the error you are getting

Comment: i am not getting any error but text transfering not start... i am sending text

Comment: Please have a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically it may be useful