# Android Bluetooth Send Private/Internal File using OBEX

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, internal, obex

Is it possible send file from Android application private directory via Bluetooth? (directory /data/data//.. (getFilesDir()))
i can't anywhere find and answer to this.

This and Intent.ACTION_SEND approach works fine with external files:
[Sending a File using Bluetooth OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577481/sending-a-file-using-bluetooth-obex-object-push-profile-opp)

However, when i try to send private file I get "Unknown file not sent"
WCat shows "BtOpp Service "Can't open file for OUTBOUND info 57"", when BtOpp throws FileNotFoundException

Thanks

Comment: No. You can copy the file from internal storage to external storage and then try to send it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = con.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator  + TEMP_FILE_NAME; //i will get file from your /data/data/...
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("plain/text");// 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/" + path));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send File"));
```

hit accept if working....
Thanks

Comment: DeepSan, please stop asking folks to accept your answers. It's just noise, and comes across as overly needy. They'll accept it if they want to.