# Unable to create content to send

Tags: android, image, bluetooth

I'm trying to send an image via bluetooth, i keep getting an error saying Unable to create content to send

The code is as follows:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("image/jpeg");     
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/test.jpeg"));  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image")); // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the path to the image is incorrect, try this:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.jpeg"));
```

Also here is an example on how to send file over bluetooth:

[Sending a File using Bluetooth OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577481/sending-a-file-using-bluetooth-obex-object-push-profile-opp)

Comment: The code i'm using above, that's not classed as programmatically transferring images??

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a file as uri you need to add `file://`

```
Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/test.jpeg")
```

or

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/test.jpg"));
```