# self-replication technique on android

Tags: android

I want my application to have self-replication capability via Bluetooth.means can send itself.
its done on j2me with Matryoshka technique and Broken Matryoshka technique ( Optimized ).

how can do it on android?

Comment: try keeping an apk of your app inside the app in raw resource and send it over i dont feel there is any legitimate way 2 do so otherwise

Comment: @droidhot no ,its not good idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is currently no way to have an Android app transmit itself over Bluetooth. You can send URLs that point to the Play store listing, but you can't actually send the APK over.

Comment: and if i wanna do it my self,can u show me a way ? some document ?

Comment: Take a look at the Obex (object exchange) code documented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577481/sending-a-file-using-bluetooth-obex-object-push-profile-opp . They are sending files but the URL sending behavior is very similar.