# android mobile support bluetooth opp

Tags: android, bluetooth

How will i know if the android mobile device supports bluetooth opp(object push profile) or not? is it vendor specific or on particular android version?

thanks a lot.
cheers.

Comment: Go through this QA once you may get some idea. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577481/sending-a-file-using-bluetooth-obex-object-push-profile-opp

Comment: hi, actually, i am currently using that code..and it work for my samsung galaxy s1 gt-i9003(android 2.2) mobile phone. But for some reason my client mobile phone samsung (dont know what model) same OS version, tells me that it is not working...so i need to find a way to trap if the device bluetooth api supports opp or not? or is there another way to do opp communication?

Answer (score 4):

i think there is support in Android for OPP.There is a path in android/packages/apps/Bluetooth/...../opp/*.java

If your version doesn't have this, i found a useful link that will help to use OBEX OPP in android. Android framework modification is needed here.

http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.in/2009/10/how-to-have-obex-function-in-android.html