# OBEX/OPP File sender, problems with initializing device address

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, obex

**Source:**

The OPs Working Solution:
[Sending a File using Bluetooth OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577481/2237445)

I am trying to use this source in order to test transfer with my app. I have also tried running with variants but the main issue I am getting is that Eclipse wants to initialize this line:

```
BluetoothDevice device;
```

to

```
BluetoothDevice device=null;
```

In which case then the app gives me an error upon running.

In another case with similar code it will flag a problem with the actual getAddress().

Am I missing something here? Is it because I need to setup a bluetooth connection previously?

Answer (score 0):

Usually BluetoothDevice is available when you find a remote device, 
Hence you should first use BluetoothAdapter to discover remotedevices then use the code to send data to the remotedevice.
you can find a great tutorial in this regard here: (http://www.developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html‎)